# C# error checking unique and listing price below and above

Tags: c#

I need to check that the ISBN is unique during data entry, and to list the price lower or above for the book. I tried to display the price but instead I'm only able to display the exact price entered.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment_3
{
class Program
{
    public static List<Book> book = new List<Book>();
    public static List<BookCategory> bc = new List<BookCategory>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int option;
        bc.Add(new BookCategory("Comedy"));
        bc.Add(new BookCategory("Horror"));
        bc.Add(new BookCategory("Adventure"));
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t1. Add new book information          |");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t2. Search book information           |");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t3. Display book information          |");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t4. Display book category             |");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t5. Exit                              |");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------------");
            Console.Write("Please choose an option : ");
            option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1: Add(book,bc);
                    break;
                case 2: Search(book,bc);
                    break;
                case 3: Display(book, bc);
                    break;
                case 4: Compare(bc);
                    break;
                case 5: Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid option ! ");
                    break;
            }
        } while (option != 5);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Add(List<Book> b, List<BookCategory> bc)
    {
        string title, isbn, author, bookCategory;
        double price;
        Console.Write("Enter the book title : ");
        title = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter the ISBN of the book : ");
        isbn = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter the author of the book : ");
        author = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter the book category <Adventure | Horror | Comedy> : ");
        bookCategory = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter the price of the book : ");
        price = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        b.Add(new Book(title, isbn, author, bookCategory, price));

        if (bookCategory == "Comedy")
        {
            BookCategory tempBookObj = bc.Find(delegate(BookCategory bcg)
            {
                return bcg.CategoryName.Equals("Comedy");
            });
            tempBookObj.BookNo++;
        }

        if (bookCategory == "Horror")
        {
            BookCategory tempBookObj = bc.Find(delegate(BookCategory bcg)
            {
                return bcg.CategoryName.Equals("Horror");
            });
            tempBookObj.BookNo++;
        }

        if (bookCategory == "Adventure")
        {
            BookCategory tempBookObj = bc.Find(delegate(BookCategory bcg)
            {
                return bcg.CategoryName.Equals("Adventure");
            });
            tempBookObj.BookNo++;
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the book category according to the list ! ");
        }
    }

    public static void Search(List<Book> b, List<BookCategory> bc)
    {
        int option;
        string target, target1;
        double target2;
        List<Book> book1 = new List<Book>();
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t--------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t1. ISBN                      |");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t2. Book Title                |");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t3. Book Price                |");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t|\t4. Back to main menu         |");
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t--------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("Please choose an option : ");
        option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1: Console.Write("Enter the ISBN of book to be searched : ");
                target = Console.ReadLine();
                Book result = b.Find(delegate(Book bk)
                {
                    return bk.ISBN.Equals(target);
                });

                if (result == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Product not found !");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                break;

            case 2: Console.Write("Enter the title of book to be searched : ");
                target1 = Console.ReadLine();
                Book result1 = b.Find(delegate(Book bk)
                {
                    return bk.Title.Equals(target1);
                });
                if (result1 == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Product not found !");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(result1);
                break;

            case 3: Console.Write("Enter the price of book to be searched : ");
                target2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Book result2 = b.Find(delegate(Book bk)
                {
                    return bk.Price.Equals(target2);
                });

                if (result2 == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Product not found !");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(result2);
                break;

            case 4: 
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void Display(List<Book> b, List<BookCategory> bc)
    {
        b.Sort();
        foreach (Book bk in b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bk.ToString());
        }           
    }

    public static void Compare(List<BookCategory> bc)
    {
        bc.Sort();
        foreach (BookCategory bk in bc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bk.ToString());
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Please reduce your question to something specific.

Comment: You really should use better variable names than `b`, `bc`, `bk`. I would suggest `books`, `categories` and `book`. Also `BookCategory` looks like it should be an `enum` rather than a list of strings.

Comment: Note: instead of anonymous methods through `delegate`, look into [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: @akton Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @Gilles Can do. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display your book details somewhat like

```
public static void Display(List<Book> b, List<BookCategory> bc)
{
    b.Sort();
    foreach (Book bk in b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bk.title  + (bk.price+10).ToString());
    }           
}
```

edit the code according to your book class.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you implemented the Object "Book?, 
you should override there the method "ToString()" and there you can decide which value you want to display when writing "Book.Tostring();"

Answer (score 0):

To get books with prices around that of the book you found:

1. Sort the books according to price
2. Locate the book you found
3. Get the books just before and after (but what if they have the same price?)

The coding is left as homework :-)

Answer (score 0):

The big `if` block in your `Add` method is wrong. Instead of:

```
if (bookCategory == "Comedy") { }
if (bookCategory == "Horror") { }
if (bookCategory == "Adventure") { }
else { }
```

... you should have:

```
if (bookCategory == "Comedy") { }
else if (bookCategory == "Horror") { }
else if (bookCategory == "Adventure") { }
else { }
```

But even better, you can improve it by using following code (it does the same thing, but a bit shorter and imo easier to read):

```
switch (bookCategory)
{
    case "Comedy":
    case "Horror":
    case "Adventure":
        BookCategory tempBookObj = bc.Find(delegate(BookCategory bcg)
        {
            return bcg.CategoryName.Equals(bookCategory);
        });
        tempBookObj.BookNo++;
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the book category according to the list ! ");
        break;
}
```

Also, since both your `book` and `bc` variables are static and even in the same class as other methods, there's no need to pass around those variables into all methods, since they can all access them anyway.

As for adding unique isbn, you can try something like:

```
do {
    Console.Write("Enter the ISBN of the book : ");
    isbn = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!books.Any(b => b.Isbn.Equals(isbn))) // or any other way of comparing
```